# Generate allure report without install in system Allure command line tools

Tags: allure

I have a project to test UI on Java Selenide. I want to show it to one company as a portfolio. I do not want them to bother installing allure command-line tools and add its bin to the PATH variable. Is it possible to generate an allure report without it?

I am talking about the Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Allure specified in your pom (and you're using Maven), after your test run you can run this:

```
mvn allure:report
```

This will generate a report in the target/site folder (click on index.html to view it)